# Multicast flash player popup in flash

Tags: flash, multicast

I have created a Flash  multicasting player. When users open it first time it shows this alert . Many people don't have idea and can get confused . Is there any way I can avoid this popup ? Or Is there any way  I can show this alert in my own gui before the player is shown so people don't get confused .

I will really appreciate your help .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  I would recommend showing a screen of instructions, including the popup dialog image, so they know what to expect, and instruct them on what to do.